# Jenkins CI with Chef Server

Tags: jenkins, chef-infra, jenkins-plugins

Is there any way I can integrate Jenkins with Chef Server so that I can create jobs to be executed? I don't want to have to go to the Chef Workstation.

Do I need to install jenkins on a separate server or the chef workstation?

Can I execute all the recipes directly from the Jenkins console?

Comment: Please be more precise.

Comment: Like I have a chef environment that consists of nodes,  chef server, chef workstation. This set up is integrated with AWS. Now how can I integrate Chef server with Jenkins so that I can create jons on jenkins and can execute them without going on to the chef server.

Comment: What jobs do you want to execute? Do you want to have CI for your chef cookbooks etc.? Or for what are the jobs? There's a [jenkins cookbook](http://supermarket.getchef.com/cookbooks/jenkins) for chef, does that already help?

Comment: Like i can execute the chef recipes from jenkins console.. Creating the ec2-server from the jenkins job like that

Comment: I still don't get your exact point. Maybe what [@Eldad AK](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1300730/eldad-ak) is suggesting with the plugin for jenkins is what you are looking for. But under what condition do you want to create the ec2-server? You then want to run chef-client on that new instance?

Comment: yes means that will provide a gui where i can pass the parameters for creating ec2 servers and then i can specify the run list on the gui

Comment: Like i have now installed jenkins on the workstation. I want to implement something like this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AgRlhY4LICM

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can create jobs in jenkins and can be integrated with chef. Knife search would be the best option. you can run chef-client to run recipes through jenkins to any machine.

Comment: `chef-clinet` shouldn't be `chef-client` ?

Answer (score 0):

Look into this [chef-plugin](https://github.com/melezhik/chef-plugin/). It might help. I have **not** tried it.

I hope this helps.

Comment: How to install this plugin on which server ?? chef workstation ?

Comment: Follow Jenkins documentation on how to install plugins: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins. Also follow the documentation of the plugin itself. As I mentioned, I've not used it so you can (and should) share your experience here.

Comment: Like i have now installed jenkins on the workstation. I want to implement something like this : youtube.com/watch?v=AgRlhY4LICM

Answer (score 0):

We managed to have this working except automatic deployment (I am doing some research if there is such thing yet).

What I recommend is having Jenkins slave connecting to your master (i.e. using Swarm plugin). This slave could be machine (i.e. Ubuntu server edition) with QEMU/KVM virtualization, Ruby, Vagrant (or other tool), ChefClien, TestKitchen, RSpecs (chefspecs) and Foodcritic. There is [Chef Development Kit](https://downloads.chef.io/chef-dk/) that has many of this.

What build do:

1. Checkout your chef repository
2. Run `kitchen test all' (or only subset of your suites)
3. If status is **0** then execute `rspec --format doc` (from yours cookbook directory
4. If status is **0** then execute `foodcritic -f`
5. If status is **0** then you can upload your cookbook `knife upload cookbooks/my_cookbook`

What we haven't figure out yet is:

- Update (increase) version of cookbook (if doing release)
- Still quite error prone approach using status and shell scripts in jenkins build

More resources:

- [Foodcritic CI](http://acrmp.github.io/foodcritic/#ci)

Answer (score 0):

try these Jenkins plugins:

https://github.com/zhelyan/jenkins-chef-api

together with

https://github.com/zhelyan/jenkins-chef-wrapper