# steps to integrate chef with jenkins

Tags: jenkins, chef-infra, jenkins-plugins

As I am new to chef with Jenkins, please let me know what are the steps to integrate Jenkins with Chef. I have installed "chef tracking plugin" and "Deployment Notification Plugin". And I don't know further steps. Chef client resides in remote (Linux OS) and jenkins in local (Windows 7).

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24861027/jenkins-ci-with-chef?rq=1) link.

But found nothing. Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please be more specific. It depends, for what you want to use Chef. Do you want to test Chef cookbooks, do you want to use Chef to deploy the software that you develop, etc.?

Comment: I want to use chef to deploy softwares.

Comment: So basically you have to write your chef cookbooks that deploy your software. Is that already working? After a build of your software, the only thing that Jenkins might do is to trigger a chef run on your production server, which can be done using [this plugin](https://github.com/melezhik/chef-plugin/). But other than that, you description is still very vague.

Comment: I have cookbooks ready and they are working fine. I need to integrate with chef so that I can deploy it using Jenkins(is it possible?).

Comment: Your cookbook already downloads the latest build from Jenkins? Then I suggest to give the mentioned plugin a try to kick off chef-client as post-build step.

Comment: One more thing I forgot to mention that is, chef- client and chef-server are installed in one remote machine. I have added cookbook in that machine  which is running properly (JBoss cookbook). I am connectiong to the machine by Putty and WinSCP.